# echo to a div rather than a blank page

Tags: php, security, html, echo

I am using this code to create a secure log in page in PHP.  I got it from http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2006/creating-a-secure-php-login-page.

```
<?php
   $username = "user";
   $password = "pass";
   $randomword = "bibblebobblechocolatemousse";

    if (isset($_COOKIE['MyLoginPage'])) {
        if ($_COOKIE['MyLoginPage'] == md5($password.$randomword)) {
?>
    CONTENT HERE
<?php
   exit;
        } else {
         echo "<p>Bad cookie. Clear please clear them out and try to login again.</p>";
         exit;
      }
   }

    if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
      if ($_POST['name'] != $username) {
         echo "<p>Sorry, that username does not match. Use your browser back button to go back and try again.</p>";
         exit;
      } else if ($_POST['pass'] != $password) {
         echo "<p>Sorry, that password does not match. Use your browser back button to go back and try again.</p>";
         exit;
      } else if ($_POST['name'] == $username && $_POST['pass'] == $password) {
         setcookie('MyLoginPage', md5($_POST['pass'].$randomword));
         header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
      } else {
         echo "<p>Sorry, you could not be logged in at this time. Refresh the page and try again.</p>";
      }
   }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> Name
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /> Password
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

It works really well, however, when there is a mistake in the log in information, it switched to a blank page and echos out a message saying the log in information is wrong.  I was wondering if there were a way to have it echo to a div on the page with the inputs.  I tried putting the relevant echo messages inside a div but it didn't work.  I must admit that I don't even know why it's going to a blank page.

Also, is this the best way to do it or is there a way to make it more secure?

Thanks for any rendered assistance.

Benny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

- The `exit` in your code stop the execution of the page so after 'echo-ing' your message, the page stops
- If you want to display in a div, set the message in a variable and display it in the div code

Here is an example of your code, re-worked a bit (you might want to adjust):

```
<?php
$message = NULL;
if (isset($_COOKIE['MyLoginPage'])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['MyLoginPage'] == md5($password . $randomword)) {
        ?>
        CONTENT HERE
        <?php
        exit;
    } else {
        $message = "<p>Bad cookie. Clear please clear them out and try to login again.</p>";
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
    if ($_POST['name'] != $username) {
        $message = "<p>Sorry, that username does not match. Use your browser back button to go back and try again.</p>";
    } else if ($_POST['pass'] != $password) {
        $message = "<p>Sorry, that password does not match. Use your browser back button to go back and try again.</p>";
    } else if ($_POST['name'] == $username && $_POST['pass'] == $password) {
        setcookie('MyLoginPage', md5($_POST['pass'] . $randomword));
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
    } else {
        $message = "<p>Sorry, you could not be logged in at this time. Refresh the page and try again.</p>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> Name</label>
        <br />
    <label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /> Password</label>
        <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    <?php
    if (isset($message)) {
        echo "<div>" . $message . "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey thanks JScoobyCed, that's worked like I wanted it to.  Many thanks.  Can you answer my question about how secure this is and if it can be made more secure?  Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Umm... There is no "best way" to do it. The link you provided is from 2006 so I guess you can look for some more recent posts. Note that using md5 for login is considered insecure because could be exploited, but if you're not protecting financial information you're probably good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting your *entire* content, including the `<html>` tags where it says `CONTENT HERE`?

The only thing that should go there is the secure content, not the whole page.  Your boilerplate html, `<html><head><title>title</title></head><body> ... </body></html>` should go around the whole block of code you posted.  The contents of `CONTENT HERE` only display with a successful login, so anything that isn't secure shouldn't be shown there.

Here's an alternative implementation of a [PHP page locker](http://www.digitalgemstones.com/code/tools/auth/authenticate.php) I wrote a long time ago, that may make this more clear.</shameless plug>

Comment: I like this one because it uses sessions.  Is this more secure?  Also, yes, I know what goes in content here.  I didn't chose this as a the accepted answer because it was about content here and not the error messages.  Still, I like your code and may go with it.

Comment: It's not a good practice to store passwords in cookies, which is what the code in your question does.  Even though it's hashed, breaking MD5 is reasonably trivial.  Much better to use a session and limit password checking to server-side.  If JScoobyCed's answer better addressed your question, I'm not offended, hope my code is helpful.  Feel free to contact me with questions / feedback, it's old, but I'd be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the result of the login if it fails, but not displaying a page with it. If you want to display the login failed page within your sites design already, I'd recommend sending them back to the login page with the error message. For example:

```
header("Location: http://website.com/loginpage.php?failed=1");
```

and then in the login page's code:

```
if ($_GET['failed'] == '1') echo "Failed to login. Please try again.";
```

This way if the login fails, they will be sent back to the login page with the error message.